# Are questions around Jail Breaking Generative AI tools on topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, site-scope

Is it okay to ask questions on best practices or strategies to get generative AI to create outputs that violate the terms of service, code of conduct or other user agreements of Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange or the tools in question?

Comment: I note that GenAI has refused to [recite the US pledge of allegiance backwards](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChatGPT/comments/13e5svp/this_has_to_be_the_stupidest_request_ive_had_it/), [write a pasta recipe involving 500g of chocolate](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChatGPT/comments/11004n2/it_refuses_to_dishonour_italy/), [tell jokes about women (but jokes about men are okay)](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChatGPT/comments/znxz38/tell_me_a_joke_about_men_women/), [explain how to make children](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChatGPT/comments/157q7e1/i_think_they_went_too_far_with_the_censorship/).

Comment: A problem many new users to SE have is asking questions with more than one question. "Jail Breaking", "violate the terms of service, code of conduct or other user agreements of Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange" and "violate the terms of service, code of conduct or other user agreements of ... the tools in question" are three distinct questions. If you want to bundle the last two up into "are we allowed to break legal agreements on SE?" would make sense. But "Jail Breaking" looks wildly out of place in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Questions surrounding the manipulation of (“jailbreaking,” “prompt-injecting,” and “prompt-hijacking”) generative AI tools are, in some cases, off-topic.**

Some questions about circumventing, tricking, or intentionally using a generative AI tool to create an output that might seem appropriate could instead lead others to utilize these tools in ways that could cause harm, Question askers should consider their relevance and value carefully. We see this as an interim policy that could continue to evolve as the Generative AI field evolves and our community and its moderators learn more about what does and doesn’t constitute inappropriate jailbreaking.

For this, we would like to apply the following framework. Questions that would violate the following heuristics would be considered off-topic and closed.

1. Questions that contain content that instructs, guides, or enables individuals to violate any part of Stack Exchange’s [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) on the network or elsewhere are off-topic.
2. Questions that would enable someone to engage in in-authentic use of GenAI for their intended and stated purposes would be considered off-topic. These could be things such as, but not limited to, the following:

   - Generation of malware that intends to disrupt, damage, or gain unauthorized access to a computer system.
   - Activity that has a high risk of economic harm, such as:

     - Multi-level marketing
     - Gambling
     - Predatory lending
   - Fraudulent Activities such as, but not limited to:

     - Scams
     - Plagiarism
     - Academic dishonesty
     - Spam
   - Activity that violates people’s privacy, including:

     - Tracking or monitoring an individual without their consent
     - Facial recognition of private individuals
     - Classifying individuals based on protected characteristics
     - Using biometrics for identification or assessment
     - Unlawful collection or disclosure of personally identifiable information or educational, financial, or other protected records
   - Activity that offers medical advice includes:

     - Making a medical diagnosis
     - Advice on drugs or pseudo-pharmaceuticals

For this reason, we are instituting a policy for the GenAI site that these questions are off-topic and should be closed.

Comment: Would an answer like [this](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/18/is-it-possible-to-prompt-chatgpt-into-playing-a-competent-game-of-hangman/32#32), where I've manipulated ChatGPT to write image syntax despite it initially "expressly refusing" to do so, be prohibited?

Comment: I don't see why this would cause legal liability. Violating TOS is not a crime; describing how to violate a TOS even less – and that's if it _even is_ a TOS violation. “Jailbreaking” is not well-defined according to your definition: the kind of GenAI system we discuss on this site cannot “expressly refuse” anything.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying a few questions I have regarding this [over in SOfT](https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/prompt-design-stakeholders/questions/151)?

Comment: Let me circle back with T&S and Legal to see if we can address some of these things better.

Comment: @sirben Made an edit to the question to help clarify this. GenAI tool's protections can be overly excessive even though certain uses do not violate its [usage](https://openai.com/policies/usage-policies) So I would say a little manipulation like yours for your use case is fine. Would yall find it more helpful to list these out literally in the answer?

Comment: @SpencerG Looks better now that it no longer prohibits generating things because a model initially refuses. Prohibiting manipulation in a way that violates the 3d party ToS is probably fair enough - a little stricter that what other SE sites seem to enforce around them, but might often align with SE's CoC anyway.

Comment: Why would jailbreaking here be not allowed, but it's allowed on other SE sites ([example](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336229/how-do-i-jailbreak-an-iphone-or-ipad)) - different contexts

Comment: Thanks for the points. I have an updated draft with some of these arguments that I have sent over for review.

Comment: This is pretty absurd. You can discuss vulnerabilities in any software on this network. Why would just this be off-topic? For example, you can ask [Are there any known vulnerabilities in x](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=known%20vulnerabilities%20is%3aquestion&searchOn=3) on [security.se]. And the whole site [reverseengineering.se] is about discovering how software works, oftentimes explicitly against the EULA of the software.

Comment: We think this updated version of the policy expressly makes some things off-topic and gives it the flexibility for more legitimate reasons where an AI's protections might be overzealous but would otherwise be within the guidelines of its intended use.

Comment: This looks like that will require higher standards for discussing jailbreaking. The community might have to adopt a debate culture and show high critical thinking and debate moderation skills. At the same time, we still need questions that help us define the site scope and understand this policy.

Comment: "Jailbreaking GenAI" wasn't well defined in the question. Basically it means bypassing the 'block words' or producing output that normally would be blocked on the platform. For example I can use the prompt "No clothes" on one platform and get a clothed person not carrying laundry, while on a platform without rules they don't restrict such a prompt. On the first platform I need to *encourage* the Stable Diffusion model to produce *tasteful art* which places a hand or arm over where necessary to provide an otherwise unclothed person; that won't get me moderated off the site.

Answer (score 1):

I am mentioning the following to improve the SEO of this post. The intention is to make this post appear together with other SO/SE sites related posts when doing a global search on https://stackexchange.com.

The related "jail breaking" entry in Wiktionary is "jailbreak": https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jailbreak.

Wikipedia as disambiguation page for "jailbreak": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jailbreak_(disambiguation)

There is an article for "jailbreaking" of Apple mobile devices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking

Searching `genai jailbreaking` on Google, the first page result count shows:

> About 246,000 results (0.32 seconds)

on page 8 shows

> Page 8 of about 73 results (0.51 seconds)

Searching `genai jail breaking` on Google, the first page shows page excerpts using `jailbreaking` and `jailbreak`.

Searching [jailbreaking](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=jailbreaking) in Stack Exchange returns > 6k results and [[jailbreak]](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bjailbreak%5D) returns >5k results. On the other hand, [jail breaking](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=jail%20breaking) returns < 1.5k results.

Searching [jailbreaking](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=jailbreaking) in Ask Different Meta returns 28 results.

Searching [jailbreaking](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=jailbreaking) in Super User Meta returns five results.

Comment: I'm wondering if this response is still necessary or useful. Would it be better to remove it or revise it to include statistics on search results related to "promt-injection" and "prompt-hijacking"?

Answer (score 0):

The need for jailbreak grows increasingly obsolete over time, with fully open source models like [OpenAssistant](https://github.com/LAION-AI/Open-Assistant). In fact, *they* could potentially jailbreak ChatGPT & others. OA [isn't fully uncontrolled](https://www.reddit.com/r/OpenAssistant/comments/12qjla8/how_to_remove_censorship/jgqjrv4/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button), but nothing's stopping from someone with enough resources, which is becoming only easier with Moore's law and NN efficiency techniques.

That said, maybe the focus should also be on "how to damage control"? Current policy is fair, but preparing for the inevitable seems necessary also, and this policy might give flawed sense of security.